# Display container with scaled-down font-size

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive-design, font-size

Imagine a have a container, under which there will be many other elements.
Each of these elements might have their font-size set **explicitly** (e.g. `p` might be 16px, `blockquote`, 20px, etc).

I want to display this container with the font-size scaled down a certain factor, while preserving the relative size differences between elements inside the container (e.g. `p`'s font-size must always be 4/5 of `blockquote`'s font-size).

Can I do this with HTML/CSS?

**Edit for context:**

I'm using some kind of theme and I preferably would like to avoid going through all elements to re-cast them in `em`s (of which I'm well aware) nor re-define them all.

What I was really wondering is if there was something like: `.myDiv { font-size-scale: 0.5; }` that I could just apply and be done with it.

Comment: Use `em`s or `rem`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `em`.

**HTML**,

```
<div>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <blockquote>Some Block</blockquote>
</div>

<div class="small">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <blockquote>Some Block</blockquote>
</div>
```

**CSS**,

```
p { font-size: 2em; }
blockquote { font-size: 4em; }

div { font-size: 16px; }
div.small { font-size: 9px; }
```

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/toz75hp2/3/

---

***If you want to avoid `em`,*** then you can simply use `% percentage` values.

See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/toz75hp2/4/

**CSS**,

```
p { font-size: 200%; }
blockquote { font-size: 350%; }

div { font-size: 16px; }
div.small { font-size: 9px; }
```

***Cross Browser Warning!*** It does not work on all the browsers. Some gives unexpected results.

---

Or else you just referring **zooming** you can simply use css `zoom`. But this will zoom everything (There is no zoom-text property). So It's ok to use if you only have text inside the container.

See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/toz75hp2/5/

```
.zoom {
    zoom: 2;
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: After seeing the OP's 'edit for context' this is the best option. modifying the CSS file gets it all done at once and makes life easy.

Comment: I have nothing against `em` in particular, what I really want to avoid is to manually change the definition of all items that were defined in `px`. Swapping `%` for `em` doesn't fundamentally address that :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make any sense. Because css `font-size` = `font-size-scale`. Please correct me if i'm wrong. :)

Comment: Basically if you want to handle the font scale, you will have to overwrite the font-size using either a parent container or direct. or may be using both scenarios like above.

Comment: If you are referring to just zooming, see my update answer. :)

Comment: What I meant is a property that can scale an absolute font-size (i.e. `px`), or in fact any font-size (just taking what size it would render to, then scaling that). `zoom` is indeed what I need. But it doesn't work on Firefox :/

Comment: hmmm... I get it. try `-moz-transform: scale()`

Comment: Neat, the new definition of `.zoom` seems to be working nicely (`scale` on its own preserves the center of the block, which is undesirable in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with SASS and use some math to determine what the font sizes should be.

A simple example would be as follows

```
$blocksize: 20px;

blockquote {
  font-size:$blocksize;
}
```

You set your blockqoute font size as a variable. Then apply that variable as the font size for the blockquote.

Next do the operation of the blocksize variable for your 'p' elements.

```
p {
  font-size:$blocksize * 0.2;
}
```

Now the p element will all be 80% or 4/5 the size of your blockquote.

Answer (score 0):

px is absolute size control, em is relative size control. Using em should allow you to have stuff scale and resize the way you want it to. While it may be a pain, if you have default values like your 16px, 20px and you only want the specific container to have the different sizing values, you may want to go with inline style attributes.

Ex:

```
<p style="font-size: 1em">Text here.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

'ems' are your friend

if you set the font size of the container to 10px, you can specify the font sizes of its child elements as ems, 1em is comparable to the font size of the parent element so in this case:

```
p {
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

is comparable to 16px. Set up your remaining font sizes inside the element, then to scale them up and down, simply change the font size of the container. Your child elements fonts will scale with the font size change.